# Why can docker not find copied files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I've tried a bunch of different solutions to similar/identical questions on here and other places and it still won't work. My goal is to run multiple docker containers for my backend and frontend (and a few others but i cut them out here since they start and run fine). The backend and frontend containers won't start up since docker cannot seem to be able to find the `manage.py` (for running the backend) and `package.json` (for installing the frontend dependencies) files.

My folder structure:

```
- docker-compose.yml
- frontend/
  - Dockerfile
  - package.json
  - node project files...
- backend/
  - Dockerfile
  - manage.py
  - more django project files...
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: 'backend'
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    volumes:
      - ./data/backend:/backend_app
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    restart: always

  frontend:
    image: node:18.14.2
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: 'frontend'
    command: npm run preview
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./data/frontend:/frontend_app
```

frontend/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.14.2

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /frontend_app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "preview"]
```

backend/Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /backend_app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
```

My (partial) docker console output when running `docker compose up`:

```
frontend          | npm
frontend          |  ERR! code ENOENT
frontend          | npm ERR! syscall open
frontend          | npm ERR! path /frontend_app/package.json
frontend          | npm
frontend          |  ERR! errno -2
frontend          | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/frontend_app/package.json'
frontend          | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
frontend          | npm ERR! enoent 
frontend          | 
frontend          | 
frontend          | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
frontend          | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-17T22_35_21_039Z-debug-0.log
backend           | python: can't open file '/backend_app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
backend exited with code 2
```

Comment: Does it also happen with `docker compose up --build`?

Comment: @FirstOne yes, it does. same output

Comment: There are several unnecessary lines in your Compose setup.  You've already gotten an answer about `volumes:` hiding your image content; you also do not normally need to specify `container_name:` or override `command:`.  More notably, the `image:` for the `frontend` container is a potential source of trouble, since you overwrite the base `node` image on build.  It may or may not help to delete this line and explicitly `docker pull node:18.14.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mounting `./data/{frontend,backend}`, overwriting anything you did on build. Your directory structure does not suggest that this is the right path.

You should mount `./{frontend,backend}` instead.

Additionally, due to fetching the dependencies (node_modules) on build, they will not be available when you do `docker compose up`, since you overwrite the container file system with the mounted host directory. So you need to ensure that you install the dependencies such that they will exist on the host system. All in all, mixing the build with the volume mounts seems a bit strange.

Comment: thank you, that was very helpful for my understanding. it works now but the npm error seems to be still there. this is a different error though and has nothing to do with this question probably